# Trying to get a count of cells between certain times in Excel

Tags: excel, time

For my Excel spreadsheet, I am copy pasting data returned from an SQL query. The dates are brought in this format: 11/26/2019 11:20. So mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. What I am trying to do is write a formula that counts how many cells appear between a certain time range, like in between 9:00am and 10:00am. I have an existing formula, which is

`=COUNTIFS(R:R,">="&TIME(9,0,0),R:R,"<="&TIME(10,0,0))`

with R being the column my dates are stored in. This formula gives me back

`1/0/1900 0:00`

which isn't what I'm looking for. Im sure this is a simpler fix, but I'm stuck.

Comment: You will not be able to use COUNTIFS with this unless you use a helper column that has only the time portion of the date/time.  Date/Time is a double with the integer representing the number of days since `1/1/1900` and the decimal as the time.  You will need to get the decimal part only to do the comparison and COUNTIFS cannot do that.

Comment: Doable with SUMPRODUCT but I agree with @ScottCraner, I'd just use a helper column here.

Comment: You can use `INT` to strip out the time: `=R:R-INT(R:R)`.

Comment: @BigBen `MOD(R:R,1)` will do it.

Comment: @ScottCraner yep, that too.

Comment: I think its : '=COUNTIFS(MOD(R:R,1),">="&TIME(9,0,0),MOD(R:R,1),"<="&TIME(10,0,0))' .. does this work ?